# Display button image outside bounds of link

Tags: html, css

Can I create button, use a background image that changes on hover and on active, and have the active state show an image that extends outside of the bounds of the anchor? Here's my sprite:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7737304/menu-sprite1.png

The top half of the sprite is 'hover', the bottom is 'active'. I don't anything below the solid bar to be a clickable link, and I don't want to set a width as the menu text will set on top and extend beyond the left and right edges of the image.

I've attempted to assign the background image to the parent li tag, which works for 'hover' but I can't make it work for 'active'.

Any ideas?

CSS

```
.navigation li:hover{
background: transparent url(../images/menu-sprite.png) center -86px no-repeat;
}
.navigation a{
color: #e8e8e8;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding:0.5em 0.8em;
}
.navigation a:hover{
color: #fff;
}
.navigation a.active {
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for JavaScript.  Why don't you look into that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/n6dEH/) ?

The anchor 'expands' when active, but doesn't change the flow, since it uses a negative margin to make it actually the same size as before.

So: add the amount of padding you want to expand the anchor, then add the same amount as a negative margin. (You do need the anchor to be a `block` or `inline-block` element, since otherwise it can't use margin)

No need for JavaScript with this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GHTph/)

It just puts the background image on the `<li>`.  Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for or not though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one to explain! What I did was to make the `a` tag clickable, extended the `li` with `::after` to which I could apply the styles necessary to make it change, but not be click able.

Like I said, tough to explain but here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/SgH5C/

And here's some CSS that may help you:

```
.navigation li::after {
    background: transparent url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7737304/menu-sprite1.png') center -49px no-repeat;
    bottom: 0px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 31px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li:hover::after {
    background: transparent url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7737304/menu-sprite1.png') center -130px no-repeat;
}
```